# SQL DENSE_RANK and PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, over-clause

I do not fully understand the query results listed for the below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpAccountsTable (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, AccountID INT, 

AccountName varchar(20), CompanyID int, CompanyName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #tmpAccountsTable (ID, AccountID, AccountName, CompanyID, CompanyName)
SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS AccountID, 'ABC Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS AccountID, 'ABC Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 3 AS ID, 2 AS AccountID, 'DEF Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 4 AS ID, 3 AS AccountID, 'GHI Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 5 AS ID, 4 AS AccountID, 'JKL Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 6 AS ID, 1 AS AccountID, 'ABC Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 7 AS ID, 1 AS AccountID, 'ABC Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 8 AS ID, 1 AS AccountID, 'ABC Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName UNION
SELECT 9 AS ID, 2 AS AccountID, 'DEF Account' AS AccountName, 1 AS CompanyID, 'Stark Enterprise' AS CompanyName

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY CompanyName) as AccountRANK, * FROM #tmpAccountsTable

DROP TABLE #tmpAccountsTable
```

Executing the above, I get the following result set:

[image: Result Set]

From my understanding of the `SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY CompanyName) as AccountRANK, * FROM #tmpAccountsTable`, a partition should have been created for all AccountId's that are the same, and they should have received the same `DENSE_RANK()` value, but as can be seen, this is not the case.

What am I missing?

Comment: All of the ranks for AccountID 1 are tied, so they are all 1, same for AccountID 2, 3, and 4. What did you expect it to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a separate value for each `AccountId`, then that should be part of the `ORDER BY`, not `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AccountID, CompanyName) as AccountRANK, *
FROM #tmpAccountsTable;
```

The `PARTITION BY` is used to reset the counter, so each `AccountId`starts over with 1.  Then the `CompanyNames` are ordered.  Because they all have the same value, the result is `1`.

Comment: "The PARTITION BY is used to reset the counter". What exactly do you mean?  I was under the impression the PARTITION BY AccountID will create a partition for all AccountID's with the same value, and therefore have the same rank value?

Comment: @monstertjie_za . . . I thought that was clear.  I mean that each `AccountId` will rank the `CompanyName` values for that account starting at 1.